Seam between element and pseudo element
I have the following arrow:


body,
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.arrow {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #156082;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  width: max-content;
}

.arrow::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 30px solid transparent;
  border-left: 30px solid #156082;
  top: -15px;
  right: -60px;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="arrow">
    <strong>This is a label</strong>
  </div>
</div>



The arrow head is 30px wide. I want to position the arrow head to start directly at the right side of the div.arrow element. I use right: -60px; to achieve this (2 x 30px because that's the width of the arrow head). However, there is still like a 1px seam between the element and pseudo element (at least on my viewport), as shown in the image below:

How is this possible? Shouldn't the ::after element directly start at the right side of the div.arrow element with how I position it? Is this due to browser rounding or rendering differences, since the seam disappears on different zoom levels?
I am aware that I can just use right: -59px; to solve this, but this feels hacky to me and I would prefer an actual solution.

https://css-shape.com/arrow/

I don’t see this problem when on IOS Safari so you may be seeing a sort of ‘rounding error’ rather than an actual CSS controlled space. Using a clip path would make it easier to control what’s happening.

Yes, the ::after pseudo-element assumes the triangle will start exactly at the right edge of the parent .arrow element. But due to subpixel rounding, the browser may interpret the position as slightly off (e.g., -60.5px instead of exactly -60px). When you use pixel values that don't align perfectly with the display's pixel grid, some browsers might round differently, creating small gaps or seams between elements.
One solution might be css-shape.com/arrow that was posted by @Temani Afif in the comments. One other might be to use calc to have better rounding.Something like: right: calc(-1 * 30px);

Using right: calc(-1 * 60px); unfortunately doesn't do the trick. I guess a clip path is indeed then the solution. I'll accept your answer.
